# Python Pandas grouping first value of group must be true

Tags: python, pandas

**What works**

With Python and the use of Pandas I am trying to group multiple rows together and assign unique Id's to them. The data is grouped based on 7 columns then also grouped with 120 minutes maximum time interval in each group.

**The problem**

One more criteria is needed per group, it has to start with true in the column 'is_unique' and true may only occur once per group. Groups without true as a first value may be filtered out.

**The data**

The data is in chronological order.

| First 7 columns | is_unique |
| --- | --- |
| A | true |
| B | true |
| B | false |
| B | false |
| c | true |
| c | false |
| c | true |

*Expected grouping*

| First 7 columns | is_unique | group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | true | 1 |
| B | true | 2 |
| B | false | 2 |
| B | false | 2 |
| c | true | 3 |
| c | false | 3 |
| c | true | 4 |

**Currently (working) code**

The following line of code groups all the groups and assigns a unique number to them.

```
df['unique_id'] = df.groupby(["country_code", "user_agent", "screen_height" , "screen_width", "os_name", "os_version", "utm_medium", pd.Grouper(key="added_iso", freq="120min", origin="start")], sort=False ).ngroup()
```

**What I have tried**

Comparing the next rows value:

```
df['unique_id'] = df.groupby(['is_unique'.nth(0) == 'true']).ngroup()
```

cumsum:

```
df['unique_id'] = df.groupby(df.is_unique.cumsum()).ngroup()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming True/False as booleans, use a simple [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) (True will count as 1 and False as 0):

```
df['group'] = df['is_unique'].cumsum()
```

if strings:

```
df['group'] = df['is_unique'].eq('true').cumsum()
```

output:

```
  First 7 columns  is_unique  group
0               A       True      1
1               B       True      2
2               B      False      2
3               B      False      2
4               c       True      3
5               c      False      3
6               c       True      4
```

Comment: Thanks! After the grouping I added the cumsum. I finally understand why this works.